# How to hold Multiple Mysql tables in Cache Memory at the same time

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a problem here. I have one "MYSQL" query which has joins from multiple tables say table A (on server A) and table B,C,D,E,F (all on server B). I have a limitation that I cant use federated and temporary tables, I can't use INFILE/OUTFILE as well (instructed strictly).

I was suggested to stored the table B in java cache and then process the query. But there are few issues as well. As query have multiple joins from multiple tables of server B I dont know how to do that using java with ResultSets.

Is there any way in java / mysql so that I can stored the multiple table in cache memory and use the mysql query like normal query?

Comment: stored procedures

Comment: Thanks but if i use stored procedure then I will get group of resultsets through java which I have to iterate one by one to get the results. This is not the approach I am looking for.